# Inner product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\mathbb{C}^{2×1}$. Suppose that $\langle e_1,e_1\rangle =2$, $\langle e_1,e_2\rangle =i$, and $\langle e_2,e_2\rangle =3$. Find $\langle \begin{bmatrix} 1\\2\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 3\\4\end{bmatrix}\rangle$.

Can anyone help me with this? I solved for the inner product and got 11. But it seems I need to use the assumptions yet I don't know how. Is this correct?
Thanks.

Comment: Your answer is when  the inner product is the usual inner product. Here a new inner product is given which does not make $e_1$ and $e_2$ orthonormal.

Answer (score 2):

When you simplify your dot product, you get
$$
\left<e_1 + 2e_2, 3e_1 + 4e_2 \right>
 = 3\left<e_1 ,e_1\right> + 4\left<e_1 ,e_2\right> + 6\left<e_2 ,e_1\right> + 8\left<e_2 ,e_2\right>
$$
Can you now finish this?

Comment: $\langle e_2,e_1\rangle=\overline{\langle e_1,e_2\rangle}$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri forgot about complex numbers, corrected